# How can i get the asin of this string using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Hi I have the following string, how can I get the B000RMTGUQ of this entire string using regex pytnon?

```
{'asin': 'B000RMTGUQ', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/515KlX4dEUL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-v3-big,TopRight,0,-55_SX278_SY278_PIkin4,BottomRight,1,22_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg', 'related': {'also_bought': ['B009QJMXI8', 'B00CNQ7MJG']}, 'categories': [['Books', 'History', 'World', 'Jewish', 'Holocaust'], ['Books', 'History', 'World', 'Religious', 'Judaism'], ['Books', 'Politics & Social Sciences', 'Social Sciences'], ['Books', 'Religion & Spirituality', 'Judaism'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'History', 'World', 'Jewish', 'Holocaust'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'Politics & Social Sciences', 'Social Sciences'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'Religion & Spirituality', 'Judaism']], 'description': "Kibbutz Buchenwald was founded in Germany in 1945 by 16 survivors of Buchenwald concentration camp. The Zionist training farm was organized to prepare Jews for emigration to Palestine. One of the founders was Yeohezkel Tydor, the author's father, who died in 1993. Baumel's narration of the kibbutz's history is divided into two sections. Part one examines the kibbutz from its creation until the departure of the founding group to Palestine in late summer 1945. Part two traces the kibbutz's subsequent history in Palestine and Germany, from the autumn of 1945 until the mid-1950s. Kibbutz Buchenwald was abolished in Germany in 1948; the kibbutz as it was founded in what is now Israel--named Netzer Sereni--still exists today. The story of these pioneers and their physical, psychological, ideological, and political struggles forms the nucleus of this absorbing book.George Cohen"}
```

Comment: Use Python's native `json` library.  But for starters, fix your JSON string (which is currently invalid).

Comment: This is a Python literal, not JSON. Use ``ast.literal_eval`` to read it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `json` to parse your string to a valid dictionary:

First note that a valid json is enclosed by double quotes. Also, note that `author"s` etc need single quotes. Hence you could do:

```
import json, re
dct = json.loads(re.sub('"s', "'s", re.sub("'", '"', string)))
dct['asin']
'B000RMTGUQ'
```

### EDIT

from the comments below, it seems you do not have a json string but rather a valid python dictionary in string format:

therefore you could directly do:

```
dc = eval(string)
dc['asin']
```

Futher more consider using `ast.literal_eval` rather than `eval`.

---

#### data

```
string = """{'asin': 'B000RMTGUQ', 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/515KlX4dEUL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-v3-big,TopRight,0,-55_SX278_SY278_PIkin4,BottomRight,1,22_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg', 'related': {'also_bought': ['B009QJMXI8', 'B00CNQ7MJG']}, 'categories': [['Books', 'History', 'World', 'Jewish', 'Holocaust'], ['Books', 'History', 'World', 'Religious', 'Judaism'], ['Books', 'Politics & Social Sciences', 'Social Sciences'], ['Books', 'Religion & Spirituality', 'Judaism'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'History', 'World', 'Jewish', 'Holocaust'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'Politics & Social Sciences', 'Social Sciences'], ['Kindle Store', 'Kindle eBooks', 'Religion & Spirituality', 'Judaism']], 'description': "Kibbutz Buchenwald was founded in Germany in 1945 by 16 survivors of Buchenwald concentration camp. The Zionist training farm was organized to prepare Jews for emigration to Palestine. One of the founders was Yeohezkel Tydor, the author's father, who died in 1993. Baumel's narration of the kibbutz's history is divided into two sections. Part one examines the kibbutz from its creation until the departure of the founding group to Palestine in late summer 1945. Part two traces the kibbutz's subsequent history in Palestine and Germany, from the autumn of 1945 until the mid-1950s. Kibbutz Buchenwald was abolished in Germany in 1948; the kibbutz as it was founded in what is now Israel--named Netzer Sereni--still exists today. The story of these pioneers and their physical, psychological, ideological, and political struggles forms the nucleus of this absorbing book.George Cohen"}"""
```

Comment: This is not a JSON, and handling it as such might lead to all sorts of different problems – e.g. other representations for null, true, false, Infinity, NaN. It might be a Python literal, in which case ``ast.literal_eval`` is appropriate – really, it is impossible to say for sure without clarification. If you insist on JSON, please recommend ``json.loads`` instead of manually creating a ``StringIO``.